# Could not load file or assembly 'Allure.SpecFlowPlugin' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: nunit, specflow, allure

I was playing around with allure.Specflow until i noticed that there is no support for specflow 3.6+, so i decided to remove it from my project.

I have removed Allure.Specflow and all dependencies, Cleaned Debug and Release folders, Restarted VS checked that there are no mentions of Allure* anywhere in the project.

The project it self builds fine, but when i try to run any test I am getting the error below.

```
OneTimeSetUp: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Allure.SpecFlowPlugin' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The error states that the package could not be found, but Why is it trying to look for it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone that is interested I have found the solution, I was referencing the package in specflow.json file

changing to the below fixed it

```
{
  "bindingCulture": {
    "name": "en-us"
  },
  "language": {
    "feature": "en-us"
  },
  "NRetrySettings": {
    "maxRetries": 3,
    "applyGlobally": true
  }
  //"stepAssemblies": [
  //  { "assembly": "Allure.SpecFlowPlugin" }
  //]
}
```